# How to create a subdomain application in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to ask on how to create a subdomain application in asp.net mvc?

Here is my scenario, i have 1 domain www.maindomain.com. Users can signup in my website and can create their personal website, like: www.john.maindomain.com.

Here are the things that i know for now:

1. You should create a custom route in mvc to handle the subdomain.
2. In development environment, you need to configure HOST file and in production environment you can setup a wildcard in DNS for subdomain.

Now, what i am missing is how will i generate the content of the site dynamically based on the users profile personal website? (The user can only select predefined layout)
Should i create a master page template .cshtml file? Then add contents in a contentplaceholder section. or should i create the content on the fly and save it to local disk?
What is the better approach?

Comment: Creating the template is the best choice.